# How to take out two integers from an array and make them two variables?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I hope your understood my question. So I am new with C# and I want to split an array into variables. Here is my code:

```
static void Main()
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int step = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int [] binary = new int [n];
    int number = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        binary[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

}
```

If `"int n = 2"` so then I will have an array with two elements. How to take out each element in the array and give to it an independent variable?

Comment: `int x = binary[0];` or simplye use `binary[0]` where you need it ? Access the array element based on index, and remember arrays index are zero based.

Comment: ahh yes of course i should use the index. Thank you :) My question was very stupid ;d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] array = new int[n];


        for(int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }



        int n1 = array[0];
        int n2 = array[1];
        //...
        //...
        Console.WriteLine(n1);
        Console.WriteLine(n2);




    }
```